# HTTP Response Code 403 for HTTPS but not for HTTP, Custom PHP Script

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, http, https

Scenario:
I have a Java application that requires some sensitive data to make some connections to services. In an effort to solve the "Do not hard-code credentials" I have created an encrypted handshake between the Java application and a remote server.

The verification is performed by a PHP script that I wrote. It works great using PHP but receives an response code of 403 when using HTTPS. I am unable to reach the script using HTTPS through the Google Chrome and Microsoft Edge browsers as well.

I contacted my server host and their response was that there was a problem with the script and they had done all that they could do. They noted an error in the logs (that I have not been able to access) that stated:

> [Mon Jul 23 22:07:18.864507 2018] [:error] [pid 33343] [client 87.118.135.66:56676] Options ExecCGI is off in this directory: /usr/local/apache/htdocs/...

Then the support staff noted:

> In my opinion this is an issue with the script itself which might be referencing /usr/local/apache/htdocs/.

After searching around for this option I created a `.htaccess` file and added the following lines:

```
Allow From All
Options +ExecCGI
```

No change, I have tried many other solutions involving `.htaccess` (too many to list here) that have not worked.

I found more solutions that indicated that my permissions were off, so I checked. I moved all of my file permissions up to `755` yet no avail. I even changed the imported file permissions to `755` even though there is no issue with it when using HTTP.

I would rather not post my security script here if I don't have too, so I created an `index.php` file in the same directory as my scripts in hopes that I could get something simple like this to respond, yet nothing.

An SSL Wildcard from Let's Encrypt is applied to the parent domain siliconmindtech.com. The test URL in question is:

Not Working
https://piknpak.siliconmindtech.com/index.php

Working
http://piknpak.siliconmindtech.com/index.php

Please advise as this is driving me crazy.

Thanks!

Comment: This is a shot in the dark, but to make the .htaccess work you need the Apache mod rewrite activated, you'll have to ask the support staff to ensure it is active, if you had access to the bash command line, the command would be 'sudo a2enmod rewrite'

Comment: @Katie Thank you for your suggestion. I believe that the support staff has it enabled since I am able to impact my access using things such as `Deny From All` in the local `.htaccess`.

Answer (score 0):

Solved,

The issue was simple, I just misunderstood the technology that I was using. I used Let's Encrypt to create a wildcard on my parent domain that would effect all sub-domains.

Well this did not work out as intended. I was still unable to access my `*.siliconmindtech.com` content with HTTPS.

In the effort of solving things I was poking around in my Let's Encrypt CPanel configuration and decided to just add an independent SSL Certificate directly to my sub-domain. Voilà! That made it work.

Thank you to all that viewed this question and commented.